# Compare Joda DateTime objects

Tags: java, jodatime

I have two `DateTime` objects.

The one object value is a timestamp type fetched from database. The other object is the current time. I need to compare and check if cuurent time is less than the timestamp fetched from database.

```
DateTime datetimeobject = new DateTime(rs.getTimestamp("endtime"));
DateTime datenow = new DateTime();
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Don't be lazy ! Read the doc of Joda time : http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [isAfterNow()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#isAfterNow%28%29) method:

```
boolean inFuture = datetimeobject.isAfterNow();
```

Comment: This worked if Timestamp object is used how timestamp it self can be compared with current time.

Answer (score 0):

isAfter() isBefore() are the methods you are looking for